# Why is Logger.isInfoEnabled deprecated for org.jboss.logging.Logger?

Tags: java, jboss, log4j, jboss5.x

I have been away from using Log4J for a few years.  I'm now working on an application under JBoss 5, using the org.jboss.logging package.  Back when I used to do this, it was a common technique to enclose the logger.info() messages inside of a check of the logging level.  This avoided relatively expensive operation of creating the info message if it was just going to be thrown out anyway.  Here is an example:

```
  if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
        logger.info("AddRedemption response: \"" 
                    + redemptionResponse.getResponseString() + "\"");
    }
```

But now I'm finding that my trusty IDE is warning me that isInfoEnabled is deprecated.  This leads directly to my two questions:

1. Why is it deprecated?
2. What should I use instead?

Thanks in advance for your help.

-mark

Comment: According to their javadoc (http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/jboss/logging/Logger.html), it's because (quoting) isInfoEnabled() "is for low volume information, you don't need this".This is kind of old but might hold some answers for you: http://community.jboss.org/blogs/dimitris/2005/04/01/the-deprecation-of-loggerisdebugenabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned on the comment, JBoss Logger *INFO* logging level is used to log low volume information. What it's not mentioned is that the INFO logging level always printed on the console(screen) so there was no logged file that captured the INFO level. It made sense for deprecating it as developers didn't need it.

There's an interesting blog by [Dimitris Andreadi](http://community.jboss.org/blogs/dimitris/2005/04/01/the-deprecation-of-loggerisdebugenabled) about certain logging level deprecation of JBoss logging.

Comment: Thank you!  I am now enlightened.